# Fixed area, largest mass -- is there a name?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, terminology, convexity

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $s_k(x)$ denote the sum of the $k$ largest entries of $x$.  The function $s_k(x)$ is well-known to be convex and is often used in optimization, such as

https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/def_sum_largest.html

My question:  is there a name for the infinite-dimensional version of this?  That is, say $f(x)$ is an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $S_v(f)$ be the largest possible integral of $f(x)$ over a sub-region whose volume is $v$.  Obviously, the optimal sub-region would just be the interior of a level set of $f$, but this seems like it would be a natural quantity that would have a name attached to it.

Comment: Sorry, I believe that one of the related links tells me that this is the "highest posterior density region" associated with $f$:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7857/whats-the-standard-name-for-sets-of-a-given-size-with-maximal-probability-or-a?rq=1 , so this is probably already answered.